# How do I use ImGui in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx, imgui

I am programming a game right now, and ran across an issue.

I cannot use ImGui, i tried ImGui.NET, ImGuiSharp, ImGui.NET.DirectX and none of which worked.

The issue was something about not being able to find the Win32 / Dx11 Entry points to the cimgui dll.

How do I use ImGui with DirectX / SharpDX?

Any Help appreciated!

Comment: If I clone this https://github.com/mellinoe/ImGui.NET, open src\ImGui.NET.sln with Visual Studio 2022 and run ImGui.NET.SampleProgram, it works fine.

Comment: it doesnt use sharpdx

Comment: You say "none of which worked" but they do work. Why do you need SharpDX? It's a dead technology. And if you're just looking for libraries or sofware, this is not the good site.

Comment: I can only use SharpDX, as my game engine depends on it, and im not going to rewrite the rendering from scratch